# solving time complexity of a recurrance relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I was working on a homework question that requires me compare `nlogn` and the recurrence below. As in whether `nlogn` is lower, upper, or tight bounded by the time complexity of below.

```
   | 5             n = 1
 --| 2T(n/2) + n   n > 1
```

I think 2T(n/2) + n reduce down to nlogn but I am not exactly sure how to solve the recurrence relation..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried recursion trees?

Comment: not too sure. My book has a lot of proofs with discrete math

Comment: recursion tree should give the result as well. you can find very easily the result since this is a popular and easy nice-looking recurrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve recurrence (I hope I did this right):

```
2T(n/2) + n
2[2T(n/4) + n/2] + n
2^2*T(n/2^2) + 2n
you find the pattern if you keep on substituting new n
2^k*T(n/(2^k)) + kn
at this point you solve for closed form using the base case then n = 1
so for n/n = 1, we set 2^k = n, so k = logn
sub in k
2^(logn) * T(1) + (logn) * n

note that 2^logn = n with base 2 and T(1) = 5 for the base case
so we obtain 5n + nlogn
5n + nlogn is just O(nlogn)
```

Since we have both as **O(nlogn)**, it is a tight bound or big Theta.

Alternatively, you can also use master theorem to easily deduct the complexity. In case you have learned it.

```
a = 2
b = 2
c = 1
```

above satisfies case 2, which is **Θ(nlogn)**, refer to wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer - You can (and should) use the "Master Theorem" to find the O-notation for this recurrence.

The Master Theorem is a handy tool to solve recurrences and it should be your first option since you can have the result quickly. You can get a hands-on with this [exercise](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi6_fi0-u3RAhUFH5AKHaS0CGoQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHotbHKmYeU7dCfhqJRuRD3VsUNdg&sig2=jUbi8PWEKlw_cN0XzfFs_Q)